# Ошибка запуска отладки Android NDK приложения в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, c++, c, visual-studio-2015, android-ndk

Создаю проект под Android NDK в Visual Studio 2015, но не могу запустить отладку на подключенном устройстве Android v6.0 - пишет что не может запустить 'run-as'. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: Ошибка запуска отладки Android NDK приложения в Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: А устройство, вероятно, Samsung?

Comment: Да, Samsung Galaxy J5 J500H/DS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась сменой прошивки. Думал что проблема в root правах. Установка root не помогла, решил откатить root и скачал в интернете оригинальную прошивку J500HXXU1BPG8_J500HOXE1BPG8_SER.zip. После установки этой прошивки через программу Odin v3.12.3 debug стал работать.

Answer (score 0):

Такая проблема на Samsung'ах бывает, судя по [багрепорту](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206581#c4).